# C++ how does the compiler synthesize the default copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

The default copy constructor that is synthesized by the compiler for
a class that does not define its own does the right thing: it copies
all the members from one object to another.

I want to do something similar. I want to write a method

```
template <typename T>
T f(const T& obj) {
 // for each member var i of obj, I want to call some method g(obj.i)
}
```

Now I don't know what the names of the member variables are.  If this was
the copy constructor, I could call the assignment operator instead of g.

Clearly the compiler does this (but maybe it does this after it has inferred
the name of the members of the class). Is it even possible to do this 
for any class T ?

Comment: if it is a POD then why not using memcpy?

Comment: @luskan: The idea is to call an arbitrary function `g` on each member, rather than copying each member.

Comment: No, its not possible to regain the functionality of the default copy constructor when you define your own, unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has some internal data structure representing each class. When it comes to synthesize the copy constructor, it can refer to this structure in order to figure out what code it needs to emit (how many copies, how each one is done, and what the addresses of the members are in relation to the source and destination object addresses).

As a mere C++ programmer, you don't have access to this internal compile-time data structure, so you're pretty much out of luck. You basically have to list the members and hope you don't leave any out.

You could perhaps do work with the preprocessor (or if not *the* preprocessor then *a* preprocessor), to annotate your struct definition with extra information that you can use to generate the list of one call for each member.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.  C++ doesn't have [method reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), though you can do this by working within a framework like Qt.  (Which btw is a great framework, I use it all the time and it provides only a paper-thin layer on top of C++.)  The compiler doesn't need to do this either--that is, it doesn't need to infer *names* of members.  It just knows the memory offset from the address of the object and the type of each member, and copies those to the target object by calling their constructors.